# Swift 5 - Dateformatter not working as expected

Tags: swift, foundation, dateformatter

I was playing around with date formatter in swift, but the **AM**/**PM** thing is not working in my code.

```swift
import Foundation
let dtstr = "Tuesday, July 28, 2020 4:15:45 PM"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "eeee, MMMM d, yyyy h:m:s a"
let date = formatter.date(from: dtstr)
print(date)
```

the output is this: `Optional(2020-07-28 08:15:45 +0000)`. However, it should be `16:15:45` instead of this. Any idea why?

Thanks!

Comment: `08:15:45` in London _is_ `16:15:45` where you are. The world is round so different places call the same moment by different times.

Comment: Also note that the output of your `print` statement is _not formatted_ so what you say in your DateFormatter is totally irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks :-) I now understand the problem :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Date` has no information about time zone, and default string representation is using a greenwich one. You can see it `+0000` part in your string.

You can get description for your own time zone like this:

```
date.description(with: .current)
```